# Can crossing over between X and Y chromosome of sex chromosomes take place?

Tags: genetics

Can it? If no, what would happen if it did?

Comment: What effort have you put in yourself to try to answer this question? Failure to show your own effort will result in your post being voted down and closed. Please update!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can, but it is rare, and typically only in the pseudoautosomal region, meaning those sections on the X and Y chromosome that have homologous genes.

The reason it's rare and more difficult is that the DNA does not match as well, so the chromosomes have trouble interacting along the length of the chromosome.  Furthermore, there are less recombinant zones available.

---

#### Sources:

- Kauppi, Liisa, Marco Barchi, Frédéric Baudat, Peter J. Romanienko, Scott Keeney, and Maria Jasin. 2011. Distinct properties of the XY pseudoautosomal region crucial for male meiosis. Science 331 (6019): 916-20.
- Hinch, AG, N. Altemose, N. Noor, P. Donnelly, and SR Myers. 2014. Recombination in the human pseudoautosomal region PAR1. Plos Genetics 10 (7): e1004503.

Comment: So even if it does, there won't be any effect? The offspring will be as normal as any other child?

Comment: Typically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it can, however, crossing over between non-autosomal chromosomes can occur. I think it depends upon what regions came to cross over, in terms of how it would affect an individual, as the y-chromosomes surpisingly has few sex related genes, and individuals only use one (X), male or female, I do not think that it would produce a really mutated individual.